# PHP/MYSQL Delete data when expire

Tags: php, mysql

I have a custom classifieds website, and in mySQL I have date_created and date_expire. I want to make a script that will delete the ads when they are expired.
The mySQL table is called: "ads" and has these columns:
"id"
"name"
"email"
"ad_headline"
"date_created"
"data_expirare"    (this is the date when the ad will expire)

Here is what I've tried: http://pastebin.com/gD56BAWY

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ads where '".date("d-m-Y", $today)."' >= data_expirare` - this is (attempting to) select all ads where today is *after* the expiry (i.e. they have already expired).  You probably want to use `<=`.  Moreover, `d-m-Y` is not a valid [literal format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html) for MySQL dates; are you storing dates as [temporal datatypes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-types.html), or as strings?

Comment: The default time format in MySQL is YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss. So (SELECT * FROM ads where '".date("Y-m-d", $today)."' <= data_expirare), If you want something that does this automatically you will need to create a scheduled task (cron)

Answer (score 5):

What you'd want to do is run a cron job every day or so (`0 0 * * *`). You'd create a PHP file in this case, then within it, run the following query:

```
DELETE FROM ads WHERE data_expirare < NOW();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
delete from ads where data_expirare < NOW();
```

execute it when you need.

Comment: +1 with your edit <strike>Just as a heads up, your query is invalid. MySQL's `DELETE` does not take in *</strike>.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this should be automated. Take a look at this article on the MySQL Event system and using it to delete expired data:
http://mrjoelkemp.com/2011/04/mysql-event-to-remove-expired-data/
Basically you can just take the best DELETE script from the previous suggestions and have it execute periodically. In his example it is run every minute, but you could probably set this to something more sporadic.

Here is the relevant link to the documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Answer (score -6):

you could use CRON to do

```
delete * from ads where data_expirare > NOW();
```

every day for example.

Comment: Again, why would you use > NOW() ?

Comment: Just as a heads up, your query is invalid. MySQL's `DELETE` does not take in *.